# Applying texture without coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures

Is there any way to apply the texture to an object without specifying texture coordinates?

Comment: A better question is: What would such a texture application look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fixed-function OpenGL, you can generate texture coordinates by activating texture coordinate generation modes. There are a couple of fixed algorithms (spherical coordinates, reflection coordinates), and there is one that multiplies a vertex component by a 4x4 matrix to generate a texture coordinate.

In shaders, you can use anything you can algorithmically generate.

However, without telling us how you want a texture mapped to the surface, there's no way to know if what you want is possible. There is no `glTextureMyObject` that does "something"; either explicit texture coordinates must be used or some algorithm must generate them.